# Can't install anything with apt: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file

Tags: apt

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 and trying to install packages. I had no problems until today, now I have those errors showing up:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Ign:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And for the package I'm trying to install:

```
$ sudo apt install gcc-10-plugin-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev
Suggested packages:
  gmp-doc libgmp10-doc libmpfr-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-10-plugin-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,927 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgmpxx4ldbl amd64 2:6.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgmp-dev amd64 2:6.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmpfr-dev amd64 4.1.0-3build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmpc-dev amd64 1.2.0-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 gcc-10-plugin-dev amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gmp/libgmpxx4ldbl_6.2.1%2bdfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gmp/libgmp-dev_6.2.1%2bdfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpfr4/libmpfr-dev_4.1.0-3build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpclib3/libmpc-dev_1.2.0-1build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-plugin-dev_10.3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

If I go to `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gmp`, for example for the libgmp-dev dependency, I can see that there is a file named `libgmp10_6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb`, but `apt` seems to be looking for `libgmp10_6.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: that's because `hirsute` is EOL, so therefore its packages are not located in `gb.archive.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: Maybe, but after seeing your first comment I triggered a full upgrade of my OS to Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to upgrade and install packages on a release that is no longer supported [announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2021-December/006305.html). Your best bet is to probably upgrade to a newer release, preferably one with Long Term Support if you don't want to upgrade (which can take a while) every 6 months.